# ViewPager not showing up with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

My app's action bar consists of a toolbar and a tab view with a ViewPager to display the page's content. I am trying to use a CoordinatorLayout as my root view instead of a LinearLayout, but when I replace `LinearLayout` with `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`, the content with my ViewPager is no longer visible. Here is the XML with `LinearLayout` as root:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <include layout="@layout/actionbar" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.whatsgoodly.views.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the app with `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` as the root view. As you can see, the content in the ViewPager is hidden/missing. (I photoshopped out the tab icons and action bar text)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe my one helps you. just customize the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:theme="@style/toolbarstyle"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white" />



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Great, my content showed up! However, I was using `CoordinatorLayout` so that the toolbar would collapse on scroll but that is still not happening. I added the tag `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to my Toolbar XML view but it still isn't collapsing. Any thoughts?

Comment: hmm i never used a collapsed toolbar before but i saw a tutorial for that [link](with a tablayout below: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqvwA58b9l8)