# Hide Toolbar on scroll with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-xml, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

My app's action bar consists of a `Toolbar` and a tab view with a `ViewPager` to display the page's content. I am using a `CoordinatorLayout` so that I can hide the `Toolbar` on scroll, but it isn’t hiding. Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <include layout="@layout/actionbar" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.whatsgoodly.views.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/purple"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp”
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar tag:

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

Comment: Hm that didn't change anything. Is there something to use in conjunction with `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` that may work?

Comment: try removing linear layout from CoordinatorLayout

Comment: When I remove the `LinearLayout` from the `CoordinatorLayout`, the content of my `ViewPager` is no longer visible. To fix that issue, I had to add a `LinearLayout` as a child element of the `CoordinatorLayout` (solution obtained from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661137/viewpager-not-showing-up-with-coordinatorlayout/32661223#32661223)

Comment: man you have given 0dp height to view pager, when you remove linear layout change 0dp height of view pager  to match_parent and remove layout_weight.

Comment: Great - I was able to remove the `LinearLayout`! However, the toolbar still is not collapsing on scroll even with `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"`

Comment: try removing all these lines android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"